# Spring Boot manual content negotiation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, content-negotiation

I'm reworking old rest api and need to keep compatibility with it. Old api uses servlets and works with both xml and json. The logic is following:

- it checks 'Content-Type' header, if it's supported ('text/xml', 'application/xml', 'application/json'), it's used as is;
- if it's not supported (e.g. '*/*', 'text/plain', 'multipart/form-data') or not exists, 'application/xml' is used;
- then 'Accept' header is checked in the same way with the only addition, if it's not present the same value as 'Content-Type' is used.

How can I achieve the same result with Spring MVC (using Spring Boot)? I tried to override configureContentNegotiation in config class, but it does not seem to work:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"..."})
public class AppConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
configurer.defaultContentTypeStrategy((NativeWebRequest request) -> {
            String header = request.getHeader("Content-Type");
            MediaType mediaType;
            if (Objects.isNull(header)) {
                mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML;
            } else switch (header) {
                case MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE:
                case MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE:
                case MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE:
                case MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE:
                    mediaType = MediaType.valueOf(header);
                    break;
                default:
                    mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML;
            }
            return Arrays.asList(mediaType);
        });
    }

    /*the rest of configuration*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpServletRequest for request header values.

```
@Autowire
HttpServletRequest request;

private String getContentType() {
    return request.getHeader("Content-Type");
}
```